# When a dot exist in the middle of the URL, the rewriter works wrong

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a project in asp net core 2.0.

I Have stablished the next Rule in the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="wwwroot" >
            <match url="([\S]+[.](js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When i acces to the url: www.foobar.com/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js for some reason the iis try to finde Chart.js in the path: wwwroot/lib/chart.js ignoring the last part of the url (/dist/Chart.js) when im expecting to take wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your regexp like this: `([\S]+[.](js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))$` it should consider file extension if they at the end of your url

**EDIT**

To your rule you should exclude urls starting from `wwwroot`

```
    <rule name="wwwroot" >
        <match url="([\S]+[.](js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/wwwroot" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="wwwroot/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: I've already do it but nothing. I think that the regexp match fine, but then only rewrites the first part

Comment: Try to change `Rewrite` to `Redirect` and then you will be able to see the actual behaviour. Just for debugging.

Comment: Wow! I get wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js

Comment: Ive also tried adding this condition <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="isFile" negate="true"> but doesnt work

Comment: Using your rules now i get the correct path: wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js, BUT im still getting 404 error. The file is there, if i change the folder name to chartjs (whitout the dot) it works, but with the dot, i get 404

Comment: When you trying to access this URL `wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js` you receiving 404. Is it correct?

Comment: When the url is lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js, the rewriter replace it by wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js and i get 404.
If i try with another working example, i write the url lib/sifter/sifter.js, and the rewriter put wwwroot/lib/sifter/sifter.js and i get the file

Comment: I have a new clew! if i change the directory name to chart.aa, its works. The problem is the .js extension, not the dot. So, with wwwroot/lib/chart.aa/dist/Chart.js everithing work ok. We need to see why the .js break it

Comment: I will open another question with these problem, because the originla its fixed with your solution